# Initramfs error. Dell XPS 13 9360 running Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, dell, filesystem, initramfs

I recently returned from a trip after five months.  I booted up the computer and when Ubuntu tried to load it dropped me to a Busybox CLI with an initramfs error.

I found some tutorials online that said it was a file system configuration error and that I would need to use fsck to fix it.  Followed some video tutorials and had no success. I couldn't even find the file system.

I tried to use a live CD to USB boot and I can't even see the file system. The Dell recovery USB said there was no file system to open.

When I booted up into Ubuntu options I used recovery mode and this error is what I received;

> Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:  
>        -Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)  
>         -Check root delay= (did the system wait long enough?)  
>         -Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)  
>       -Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev) ALERT! UUID=0f074e32-e9a3-4b09-9f83-8858ec5975a1 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!  
>   [  48.745349] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid  
>   [  48.745781] usbhid: USB HID core driver
>
> Busybox etc...
>
> (initramfs)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm not a poweruser so be gentle on me. Apologies for the formatting.

Edit: @heynnema when following the video tutorials I would type fsck /dev/sda1 and get no results. Then I would try fsck /dev/sda2 etc. All with no results.

Now, when I typed in lsblk /dev/sda the response I get is; 
NAME    MAJ:MIN    RM    SIZE    RO    TYPE    MOUNTPOINT 
sda      8:0       1     14.66    0    disk 
--sda1   8:1       1     14.66    0    part /cdrom

When I type in  sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda the response I get is; 
fdisk: invalid option -- '1' 
Try 'fdisk --help' for more information

Comment: The error information should have given you more information about what device it was having trouble with. Do you remember what `fsck` command you used? Boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD, and in `terminal` type `lsblk /dev/sda` and `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`... edit that info into your question... not into the comments please. Let me know when you're done. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema responded to reply

Comment: `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` the middle character is a lower case L, not a number one. Let's also try `sudo blkid`. Does your BIOS see the drive?

Comment: @heynnema sorry about the first one. tried with the -l and your second command.  In neither case does the BIOS see the drive.  Just the USB.

Comment: Is this a laptop or a desktop?

Comment: @heynnema its a Dell XPS 13 9360 Developers Edition laptop and came factory installed with Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I would get the Service ID # from a tag on the bottom of your laptop, and call Dell Support. You may have a hardware problem.

Comment: @heynnema I was hoping you wouldn't say that but you are most likely correct. This laptop has been a money pit.  Thank you for your help.